# helmignore double-star syntax is not supported in helm 3

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to ignore specifics files in subchart folder (because some objects, like secrets, are created by all my subchart, so duplicated...). I don't know the depth of these objects. So I want to use this syntax in .helmignore :

```sh
charts/**/myfile.yaml
```

But I got this error :

```sh
Error: double-star (**) syntax is not supported
```

How can I do that in helm 3 ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this feature doesn't supported nether in helm2 nor helm3.

- helm2 source code: [link](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/dev-v2/pkg/ignore/rules.go#L139-L142)
- helm3 source code: [link](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/internal/ignore/rules.go#L135-L138)

Try to ignore it explicitly:

```
$ cat .helmignore
secrets
# or 
./secrets/my-secret.yaml
```